# document.writeln replacement in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm reading in JavaScript for Dummies, page 29 and it is showing the document.writeln command.  I think I remember someone on a previous question of mine tell me not to use document.writeln any longer.

Q: If I were to tell a co-worker "Ah man!  Don't use document.writeln!  Use this instead!", then what jQuery function/plugin would I use to supplant document.writeln? I'm thinking:

```
writeln = function(X) {
$('body').append(X + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `document.writeln()` is that the results will change depending on where in the page you put the script. Your code always appends text to the end of the `<body>`, so it doesn't have that problem, but it's also not particularly useful. (Also, `writeln()` doesn't append a `<br>`, it appends a line break. There's a difference.)

The proper way to insert text dynamically is to create an HTML element that will hold the dynamic text, and set the content of that element:

```
<p>Good morning <span id='userName'>unknown user</span>.</p>

...


$('#userName').text('Mike') // or append(), or html()
```

Comment: Well, document.writeln is usually used for debugging proof-of-concept type stuff.  So let's say you wanted to show the value of a variable on the page (not the console).  Would you have a function that creates a div called "debugging" or something like that?

Comment: That's pretty much what I do, except I usually just create the div in the static HTML.